# Detect and weave dependencies automatically with AspectJ

Tags: aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

We have a Maven project with multiple compile dependencies and every time a new `<dependency>` is added, we need to create an equivalent `<weaveDependency>` entry in

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                        <groupId>a-group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>new-dependency</artifactId>
                    </weaveDependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
                <weaveDirectories>
                    <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</weaveDirectory>
                </weaveDirectories>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is being done exactly as described in
 http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveJars.html

But this could easily lead to problems if it's needed to weave everything because someone could forget to add the `<weaveDependency>` after adding a new `<dependency>`, so is there a way of detecting and weaving all compile dependencies automatically? Maybe with another plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such option or plugin, unless you decide to write one or open a ticket for AspectJ Maven.

One question before we continue: Are you really sure you want to weave *all* dependencies? What about libraries such as JUnit or Log4J in your aspect POM?

The way I usually go about weaving my aspects into the code - if they are production and not just development, debugging or profiling aspects, that is - is that I do it the other way around than you: I use the AspectJ Maven Plugin in each of my modules to directly compile the aspects into my code from source. So in my case each Java module depends on an aspect module, using it as an aspect library. Because usually I have way fewer aspect libs than Java modules, I cannot so easily forget to include them. Okay, I have to do it in each module, but this is a no-brainer with a good IDE (global search and replace on all *pom.xml* files in my project).

If you really want to do it even more cleanly and nicely, you can use the approach explained in [Strategies for using AspectJ in a Maven multi-module reactor](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/multimodule/multimodule_strategy.html), i.e. you create a normal root POM and an aspect root POM which has the root pom as its parent. Then each Java module which needs the aspects can use the aspect root POM as its parent, other Java modules use the root POM directly.

The advantage of compiling the aspects into your artifacts right away is that there are no two class file versions of each artifact: an original without aspects and a woven version with aspects in the aspect module's *target* directory. The only reason why you would *not* do it they way I explained is if for some reason you also need artifact versions without aspect code. But then, as I said, you probably use development, debugging or profiling aspects. Be it as it might, you can still use my approach for production aspects and your old approach for the development stuff.

Comment: your approach worked perfectly. I just finished refactoring all projects to use it and now they look much cleaner, thank you